# C++ syntactic sugar or technique for prototype generation when using template specialization

Tags: c++

I wonder what is the preferred C++ way for the generation of method prototypes,
when using template specialization? The technique I'm after
should scale well with the number of the foo class methods, see below.

The marked block of the reproducer has to be replaced.
Please no code snippets managed by hand or by a script.
Some additional small modifications (perhaps in the header) might be possible.

For brevity the templated class A is placed beside the typedef for Aint.

CRTP solutions are disfavored. Usage of C++17 (not later) is allowed.
Has to compile with VS2019 recent g++ and clang++.

Edit 2020-02-09:
Removing the marked block all together,
this compiles fine with
Compiler Explorer's x64 MSVC 19.14 compiler.
So do we have a compiler issue here for g++ and clang++?

```
// begin of testspec.h
template<class T>
class A
{
public:
    A();
    void foo1();
    void foo2();
    void foo3();
};

typedef A<int> Aint;
// end of testspec.h

// begin of testspec.cpp
#include "testspec.h"

#include <iostream>

/////////////// can this block be simplified? //////////
template<>
void
A<int>::foo1();

template<>
void
A<int>::foo2();

template<>
void
A<int>::foo3();
/////////////// can this block be simplified? //////////

template<>
A<int>::A()
{
    foo1();
    foo2();
    foo3();
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
}

template<>
void
A<int>::foo1()
{
    std::cout << "foo1" << std::endl;
}

template<>
void
A<int>::foo2()
{
    std::cout << "foo2" << std::endl;
}

template<>
void
A<int>::foo3()
{
    std::cout << "foo3" << std::endl;
}
// end of testspec.cpp

// begin of main.cpp
#include "testspec.h"

int main()
{
    Aint a;
    return 0;
};
// end of main.cpp
```

Comment: what do you want to simplify? If methods are the same across different specializations you should rather move them to a non-template base class

Comment: No! the foo methods are NOT the same across the different specializations. But if there are much more than 3 foos one has to place for each of the foos an additional  prototype in the file. This is annoying.

Comment: You should be able to get rid of the entire block if you define the specializations in the header file: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53fec7462301c2d7

Comment: Kinda trite answer but: It can be simplified by defining the specilizations before usage.

Comment: @NathanOliver, Many specializing classes many foos. The specializations have to go into the .cpp files (hard requirement).

Comment: If you intend to have constant template specializations, why have the template in the first place?

Comment: @jxh, brevity,  many specializing classes many foos, without the template the class interfaces differ only in one type. Of course, you could put the whole interface in a big macro, but you will probably loose supporting features within the used IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is a part of `A` that does not get specialized, then the portion of `A` that you are trying to allow for modifiable behavior via specialization can be accomplished by adopting a [*policy pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

```
class APolicy {
    template <class, class> friend class A;
    void foo1 ();
    void foo2 ();
    void foo3 ();
};

template <class T, class P = APolicy>
class A {
    void foo1() { P().foo1(); }
    void foo2() { P().foo1(); }
    void foo3() { P().foo1(); }
};
```

And then instead of specializing `A<int>`, you implement a policy `IntPolicy`, and then instantiate `A<int, IntPolicy>`.